# Existe uma maneira de criar uma classe privada em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu queria criar uma classe onde ela pudesse ser acessada na biblioteca que eu criei, tem como eu fazer declarar a classe como privada e podendo ser chamada apenas na biblioteca?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isso em C++.

Na verdade em nenhuma linguagem há proteção definitiva para evitar uso. Quando há alguma medida protetiva no acesso à alguma parte do código só funciona se o programador não insistir. Não é proteção no sentido de proibir, mas sim de inibir. Você disponibilizou a biblioteca então é possível acessá-la.

Em linguagens como C# que tem um nível de visibilidade interno que inibe que membros externos chamem aquela classe, nada impede de fato que seja chamada. C++ nem isso tem.

Se isso for suficiente é simples de resolver. Não forneça os arquivos com protótipos que são necessários para quem for usá-los poder compilar o código.

Na verdade não documentar a classe publicamente já costuma ser suficiente para evitar uso externo.

Dependendo da sofisticação desejada pode optar pelo [Pimpl idioma](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: vlw eu queria uma forma de usar em C++ porque tenho um programa pra fazer,e como quando eu colocava constantes de classes para poder usar apenas em uma classe específica do meu algoritmo,o compilador dava pal,porque nao tinha como setar um valor na classe,sendo ela uma constante que não poderia ser modificada,ai então pensei nisso,mas depois que ce disse isso ai axo que eu vo tentar pensar em outra forma de solucionar o meu problema sem precisar de muita complicação,vlws

Comment: Me parece que agora está falando de uma outra coisa completamente diferente. Mas não entendi nada.